# abortBroadcast(); not working in SmsReceiver broadcast

Tags: android, performance

Can somebody help me with aborting notification and deleting the message received on `android 6.0.0 (marshmallow)` and above ?

I tried `abortbroadcast()` but it is not working .

This is my code:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    LocationManager lm;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    String senderTel;
    Context context;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        this.context = context;
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            senderTel = "";
            Log.e("Broadcast ", "called");
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            if (msgs != null) {
                Log.e("Broadcast", "msg read");
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        senderTel = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();//getting Number
                    }
                      abortBroadcast(); 
                }

}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this particular `BroadcastReceiver` is listening for `Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`.

That particular broadcast is sent by the system's `InboundSmsHandler` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/8c4891c01bd59bee7a1cdf1f992e6078896bea00/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/InboundSmsHandler.java#802).

You'll notice when the system broadcasts the `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`, the broadcast is not just run with `context.sendOrderedBroadcast()`; rather it is sent via `context.sendOrderedBroadcastAsUser()` *for each running user*.

On Android, each application runs as its own user.

What that means is that each application that has permission to receive SMS messages will get its own broadcast for each SMS message, and your application cannot prevent other applications from receiving that broadcast by calling `abortBroadcast()`.

Calling `abortBroadcast()` should, however, prevent any future BroadcastReceivers from your own application from receiving that broadcast.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. but on android 4.4.2 and earlier versions ,abortbroadcast() doesnt send the incoming message to message inbox and also prevents the notification ,

Comment: That appears to have changed [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/a2ce002a0327f0deb079cc6acad1c493e6ded442%5E%21/#F1), which happened post-4.4.2, and changed the broadcast to go to all users individually instead of of simply calling `sendOrderedBroadcast()`.

Comment: so its not possible to abort the broadcast post 4.4.2?

Comment: It would appear that the answer is no, which makes sense considering there may be system level apps and services that want to know about SMS messages for various reasons, and other apps may also want to know about SMS messages (a second SMS app, for example).

Comment: okay . so you basically mean there is no way of aborting message post kitkat (4.4.2) version unless the app is set to default messaging app .

Comment: I'm not sure about what functionality default messaging apps have, but I would say that no, it is not possible post-kitkat